# Dart: Null-safety and retrieving values from maps

Tags: flutter, dart, types, dart-null-safety

there is one thing I can't quite wrap my head around concerning null-safety in Dart, and that concerns how to safely retrieve values from `Map<String,dynamic>` (I've read the [FAQ](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-do-i-signal-that-the-return-value-from-a-map-is-non-nullable) from the Dart docs).

Basically, the following code in the [DartPad with null-safty enabled](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) is valid:

```
void main() {
  int i;
  Map<String, dynamic> map = {"key": 1};
  i = map["key"];
  print(i);
}
```

Which I do not understand. Why can I assign `map["key"]` to `i` without the compiler shouting at me? From the [docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety):

> Code should be safe by default. If you write new Dart code and don’t
> use any explicitly unsafe features, it never throws a null reference
> error at runtime.

But exactly this is happening. If, in the code above, the key is not in the map, or contains some random type, the program will crash on runtime, which I though is what should never happen with null safety.

I'm particular interested in this since I'm writing a Flutter app and don't understand how to properly deserialize the JSON data I fetch from the DB (`try..catch`? Special syntax like `??=` ?). Even though I don't have the 'non-nullable' language feature enabled (I can't even write `int? val` without getting a warning), the compiler does not seem to mind that I assign nullable values to non-nullable variables, and will happily crash on runtime if they are null.

Basically, my question does not only concern null-safety, but the type system in general, since from my understanding it shouldn't be possible to assign a `dynamic` value to an `int` variable, but obviously this works with `Map`. Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have no analysis error because your `Map` is declared to have `dynamic` values.  Therefore its `operator []` returns `dynamic?` which is the same as `dynamic`. The `dynamic` type disables static type checking and relies entirely on runtime checks.  If you want a proper analysis error, declare your `Map` with a non-nullable value type (e.g. `Map<String, Object>`). (Arguably the analyzer should recognize this case and insist that `i` should still be nullable, but I don't know whether that's actually possible.)

Comment: Additionally, if you set [`implicit-casts: false`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) in your `pubspec.yaml` file, you should get an analysis error about the `dynamic` to `int` assignment. (I thought that implicit casts were implicitly disabled with null-safety, but maybe there's some exception for implicit casts from `dynamic`.)

Comment: @jamesdlin For `implicit-casts: false`, you mistakenly wrote `pubspec.yaml` in place of `analysis_options.yaml`. I think the reason why it is not `false` in null-safe Dart could be that even when you're sure the data from your json is non-null, you'll have to use `int? i = map['i'];` and thereafter handle that `null`. In some cases you need that behavior and in some you don't. By the way, your first comment deserves a place in the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic variable can contain any data type, "dynamic" keyword is used when you don't know the specific data type that might be returned.

and what you're actually doing here:

i = map["key"];

is assigning a "dynamic" variable to an "int" variable and since dynamic in this case the value in the key/value pair of your Map is an integer which matches the data type "int" of variable "i" it won't crash because of type inference done at runtime and not compile time. if the "dynamic" variable was a String it would crash at runtime because of a type mismatch. Hope this is explanatory.